# Show Objective-C class in DTrace output

Tags: objective-c, macos, dtrace

Using the following DTrace script, I can get an output that is close to what I want:

```
$ cat script.d
objc$target:::entry {}
objc$target:::return {}
$ sudo dtrace -F -s script.d -c /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
dtrace: script 'script.d' matched 105896 probes
CPU FUNCTION
  0  -> +load
  0  <- +load
  0  -> +load
  0  <- +load
  0  -> +load
  0  <- +load
  0  -> +load
  0  <- +load
  0  -> +initialize
  0  <- +initialize
  0  -> +alloc
  0    -> +allocWithZone:
  0      -> +self
  0      <- +self
  0      -> +initialize
  0      <- +initialize
  0      -> +initialize
  0      <- +initialize
  0      -> +initialize
  0      <- +initialize
  0      -> +__new:::
  0      <- +__new:::
  0      -> +immutablePlaceholder
  0      <- +immutablePlaceholder
  0    <- +allocWithZone:
  0    -> -initWithObjects:count:
  0      -> +__new:::
  0      <- +__new:::
  0      -> +initialize
  0      <- +initialize
  0      -> +new
  0        -> +alloc
...
```

I would like the output to include the class called, so it would like something like this:

```
dtrace: script 'script.d' matched 105896 probes
CPU FUNCTION
  0  -> +[classX load]
  0  <- +[classX load]
...
```

where `classX` is the correct class.

The output should still be indentend and only include Objective-C messages and not C function calls.

Comment: 'Tis tricky. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/26/objective-c-printing-class-name-from-dtrace/

Comment: @bburn Isn't that only for `forwardMethod()`?

Comment: @bbum Also DTrace can see the classname, because it can filter by classname with eg. `objc$target:*NSDate*::entry {} objc$target:*NSDate*::return {}`

Comment: The class names may or may not be present because of the way the dynamic linker works.  Dtrace doesn't normally trigger paging in of memory, hence the tricky bits related to copying the class name.  Some of that may or may not be necessary and, without, it might only work some of the time.   You'll likely need to modify your script to push/pop data manually vs. relying on the automatic mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a script, which does exactly what I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dtrace -s
#pragma D option quiet

unsigned long long indention;

objc$target:::entry
{
    method = (string)&probefunc[1];
    type = probefunc[0];
    class = probemod;
    printf("%*s%s %c[%s %s]\n", indention, "", "->", type, class, method);
    indention++;
}
objc$target:::return
{
    indention--;
    method = (string)&probefunc[1];
    type = probefunc[0];
    class = probemod;
    printf("%*s%s %c[%s %s]\n", indention, "", "<-", type, class, method);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s
#pragma D option flowindent
objc$target:::entry,
objc$target:::return
{
    trace(probemod);
}
```

From [Colin Wheeler](https://stackexchange.com/users/1999/colin-wheeler)'s [Debugging Cocoa with DTrace](http://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Debugging-Cocoa-with-DTrace.pdf).